# How to get and convert attributes after tag <product to xml | XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

output date:

```
<products>
<group>
<product id="73" symbol="LEC-PY1010C" ean="5901436709251" price_pln="29.05" price_eur="6.56" tax="23.0000" stock="1215">
<name>PY1010C Głośnik samochodowy PY-1010C 4" 60W</name>
<description>test</description>
</product>
</group>
</products>
```

XSLT `1.0`

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="products/group">
<xsl:element name="products">
    
  <xsl:for-each select="product">
    <xsl:element name="product">
                    
                    <xsl:element name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="description">
                        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
  
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
<product>
<name>PY1010C Głośnik samochodowy PY-1010C 4" 60W</name>
<description>test</description>
</product>
</products>
```

Okay. Can anyone have an idea how to get these elements after the `<product` tag?

The expected result some like this:

```
<products>
<product>
<id>73</id>
<symbol>LEC-PY1010C</symbol>
<ean>5901436709251</ean>
<price>29.05</price>
<stock>1215</stock>
<name>PY1010C Głośnik samochodowy PY-1010C 4" 60W</name>
<description>test</description>
</product>
 </products>
```

@update
The solution works great but we have a small issue.

output date:

```
<product id="73" symbol="LEC-PY1010C" ean="5901436709251" price_pln="29.05" price_eur="6.56" tax="23.0000" stock="1215">
```

Currently via solution from answear we get all this attributes.

1. `id="73"` - this attribute will conflict with our site and I do not want to get it.
2. `symbol="LEC-PY1010C"` - is it possible to add our own code before this code?

example result from above:

```
<symbol>CPF-LEC-PY1010C</symbol>
<ean>5901436709251</ean>
<price_pln>29.05</price_pln>
<price_eur>6.56</price_eur>
<tax>23.0000</tax>
<stock>1215</stock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather trivial exercise. You should have known how to do this after spending an hour with an XSLT tutorial.

See if this works for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="group/product">
            <product>
                <!-- create elements from attributes -->
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <!-- copy child elements -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="name | description"/>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

***--- added ---***

Regarding your update, I would suggest using a different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="group/product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>  
    
<xsl:template match="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="@symbol">
    <symbol>
        <xsl:text>CPF-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </symbol>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  it works great. But I have one question. Because currently this copy all attributes. And  before copy attribute "symbol" we want to add our own number, eg CPF-symbol Do you have any idea how we can do this?

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow. Please edit your question and show the result you want to get.

Comment: can you please check my update question. Thanks.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.